# Can't read custom header in HttpResponse from HttpClient in a Ionic Angular application

Tags: angular, rest, http, ionic-framework

I'm requesting an endpoint that creates a new resource and returns a 201 response containing a "Location" header with the newly created resource:

[image: Network inspecting on Chrome]

However, when I try to get header value as described in [Angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response), I get a "null" value instead of the actual value. Here is my code (note: I'm setting responseType:'text' to avoid Json parsing error as the response body is empty):

```
(...)
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

(...)

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    let obj = {nome : "SomeName"}
    this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/categorias", obj, {observe: 'response', responseType: 'text'})
    .subscribe(
        (resp) => {
          console.log(resp.headers.get('Location'));
        }
      );
  }
```

I even tried console.log(resp.headers) in order to check this object, and it shows a completely different structure:

[image]

How can I get a custom header from a HttpResponse object from the new HttpClient Angular API?

Comment: What is the type of http? HttpClient?

Comment: Yes. HttpClient.

Comment: Cant you set a break point and see what is contained in resp.headers? Or maybe do a console.log to see if the the headers are actually set

Comment: thought or setting interceptor, using which you can send response header of your wish?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I tried that. I've edited the question with that information.

Comment: try use only {observe: 'response'}

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue with the `eTag` header : this is a **Cross Origin issue**.

From what I remember, CORS return only a couple of simple headers, such as Cache-Control, Content-Language, Content-Type, Expires, Last-Modified, etc.

If you want to return a specific header, you have to add another header, [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers), containing a list of the headers you want to return with it. So, in your case, `Access-Control-Expose-Headers = 'location'`.

You also obvioulsy need to change your backend to return the same header to Angular.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 5):

I had that problem too. In my case I saw only Content-Type, Pragma and Expiration headers.

In fact, that is not a Angular issue. The reason that there are not headers that you expect is a CORS.

Adding `'access-control-expose-headers' : 'Location'` on the API solves your problem :)

Comment: The image in the question shows that the location is being supplied by the API

Answer (score 1):

```
        Response.Headers.Append("myCaptchaName", "value");


services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowMyOrigin",
                builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyHeader().
                AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials()
                .WithExposedHeaders("myCaptchaName"));
        });
        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowMyOrigin"));
        });
```