# Bug in Angular HttpClient or using it incorrectly?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to access the HttpHeaders from an HttpErrorResponse but I cannot see all the headers, am I using the HttpClient incorrectly or is this an Angular bug:
[Sample demonstrating the problem](https://embed.plnkr.co/wEv4TZcWoHWytuiaFZoW/)

I can see in the developer tools that there should be the following header `WWW-Authenticate:Bearer realm="spotify"` however it is not present.

Comment: Read the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Comment: I have read the documentation and that is for getting the full response in the happy path not the error response I have already tried adding {observe: 'response'} and it just changes the normal response type: https://embed.plnkr.co/EDLjgWUjrXkNm3uNpgRl/ Please take more than two minutes before down voting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue with the `eTag` header : this is a **Cross Origin issue**.

From what I remember, CORS return only a couple of simple headers, such as Cache-Control, Content-Language, Content-Type, Expires, Last-Modified, etc.

If you want to return a specific header, you have to add another header, `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`, containing a list of the headers you want to return with it. So, in your case, `Access-Control-Expose-Headers = 'WWW-Authenticate'`.

You also obvioulsy need to change your backend to return the same header to Angular.

Hope this helps !

Comment: It sounds like it might be the right track however I wonder why I only see Content-Type by default

Comment: `From what I remember, CORS return only a couple of simple headers, such as Cache-Control, Content-Language, Content-Type, Expires, Last-Modified, etc.`

Comment: Seems like Content-Type is one of them :P

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47884516/6294072 ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/47815462/6294072 Choose the best question and mark others as duplicates if you feel they are. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled