# HttpInterceptor for TypeScript client by AutoRest

Tags: angular, typescript, autorest

I'm quite new to TypeScript and Angular. I have http interceptor:

```
export class HttpTokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const headersConfig = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    };

    headersConfig['TEST'] = `TEST`;

    const request = req.clone({ setHeaders: headersConfig });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

And when I send GET request via HttpClient from '@angular/common/http' `let resp = await this.http.get('http://localhost').toPromise();` I can see in headers my TEST header item.

Also I use autorest for generating TypeScript client for my rest services (@microsoft.azure/autorest-core: 2.0.4302) and when I call any method of generated client custom TEST header is not added to the query.
I thought that AutoRest generates also HTTP queries via the same HttpClient which should have been handled by `HttpInterceptor`...
Maybe I'm doing this completely wrong, should it be working at all in this way? Or is there a way to intercept http requests made by AutoRest generated code?

Comment: [Maybe this could help ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47815093/cant-read-custom-header-in-httpresponse-from-httpclient-in-a-ionic-angular-appl)

Comment: @Maryannah thank you for your response, but I use the same origin so it can't be CORS. Also header is really added when plain HttpClient is used

Comment: Maybe you should pay more attention to the link. It says that custom headers get remove when not exposed, which seems to be your case.

Comment: @Maryannah There is not a problem when header is blocked, issue is that interceptor is not fired. I found out that AutoRest uses another http client, not one from 'angular/common/http', that's the reason interceptor is not working. If I call method like `const res = await client.token.get(creds.UserName, creds.Password, {customHeaders: { 'TEST': 'TEST' }});` then this header is added.

Comment: did you found solution for this? I'm facing the same problem.